# How to get fare tax of flight by using the OTA_AirPriceRQ API

Tags: sabre

I'm using the OTA_AirAvailRQ API to get a list of available flights.I want to get the fare and tax information on the flight but the OTA_AirPriceRQ API gives me an error.

This is my request:

```
 <OTA_AirPriceRQ Version="2.17.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
           <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2019-02-21T17:00" ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="2019-02-21T15:00" FlightNumber="802" ResBookDesigCode="Y" RPH="1">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KUL"/>
                <MarketingCarrier Code="OD" FlightNumber="802"/>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="SIN"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
            <OptionalQualifiers>
                <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="USD">
                    <PassengerType Code="ADT" Force="true" Quantity="1"/>
                </PricingQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
    </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
```

This is the response of the API:

```
 <OTA_AirPriceRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.17.0">
        <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-01-29T02:59:18-06:00">
                <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    <stl:Message>FORMAT, CHECK SEGMENT NUMBER-0003</stl:Message>
                    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
        </stl:ApplicationResults>
    </OTA_AirPriceRS>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove the OriginDestination node in your request. As per service's design that's not used:

```
<!-- Optional -->
<!-- Repeat Factor=0 -->
<!--Please note that this node is reserved for future expansion and is not currently in use.-->
```

I would advise to use the ReturnHostCommand="true" attribute in the main request node to be returned the WP format and to be able to see what format you are sending to native Sabre.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question,
I call it, with ReturnHostCommand="true" in main request node, and WP response return is <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="222222">WPMUSD¥P1ADT¥XO¥RQ</stl:HostCommand>
Can you tell me , after call OTA_AirAvailRQ API to get flight available. Next step, what api call to get fare and tax of each flight.
Thanks you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay replying back. I think you could use OTA_AirBookLLSRQ to book the flights and then OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ. Don't you get the fare details like this?

Comment: Thanks @Telmo . 
Yeahh , i want before book flight,  users can show infomation of flights with fare and taxes . I'm seeing BargainFinderMaxRQ API is used to search for the lowest available priced itineraries, it return full infomation with different airlines, but I'm want to get all flight of only marketing airline (Ex: OD). Can I follow these steps to resolve for this solution ?

Comment: You should be able to use "Airline Marketing="OD"" in the request. Then you could use EnhancedAirBookRQ which does both the booking and pricing of the itinerary (it will combine OTA_AirBookLLSRQ and OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ) to obtain all the fare data.